# Initialization Order of Spring Aspects / Advisors

Tags: java, spring, initialization, aop, aspect

Is there a way to configure in which way different Aspects (or their corresponding Advisors to be more precise) in Spring are initialized? Note that I am not talking about the advice order, but the initialization of the aspects.

The background of this question is a use case with `Aspect A` dependent on `Service X` which should be advised by `Aspect B`. However, as `Aspect A` gets initialized first and enforces the creation of `Service X`, `Aspect B` is not applied to the service.

How can I change the initialization order without making `Service X` dependent on `Aspect B` (this would be a workaround as it enforces the desired order, but a service should never have to deal with its aspects...)?

If you want the big picture of my issue, [here is another question which led me to asking this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512791/spring-service-with-cacheable-methods-gets-initialized-without-cache-when-autowi)

Answer (score 0):

An aspect is typically just an `@Aspect` annotated class that is also annotated with `@Component` or that has a corresponding `<bean>` definition. In other words, it is just a bean.

The only ways to define the order that beans should be initialized is with the `depends-on` property (or `@DependsOn`) or by playing with the order in which you import contexts.

Comment: okay, so if my `Aspect B` is a cache automatically created via `@EnableCaching` and not explicitly put together by me, there is no way to wait for its creation in a more abstract way than depending on `BeanFactoryCacheOperationSourceAdvisor` (which is the last relevant bean of the caching aspect), right? So it would no longer work if the default beans for spring caching change in the future...

Comment: @chk I think the best you could do is put it in a `@Configuration` class that is imported by another.

Comment: hmm, that did not unfortunately not really help. It affects the order in which Beans explicitly defined in different Configurations are initialized, but that does not seem to work for the Beans implicitly declared by `@EnableCaching`...